# Keep backing up (copying) the same file to a new folder

Tags: scripts, files, backup, cron

I am saving a stream in my HDD.
I'd like to copy the file periodically into a subfolder `backup` such that the older versions of the the file are not deleted.

Simply put

1. Assume the original file is `somefolder/data`.
2. The first backup should be `somefolder/backup/data.1`
3. The second backup should be `somefolder/backup/data.2`
4. This process should continue in an interval of t minutes/seconds

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

oneline bash command finally did the trick

```
while : ; do cp -vt ./backup/ --backup=numbered -- data; sleep 5; done
```

The only qualm for this seems to be it saves the backups as `data.~n~`

Answer (score 0):

Basic, adapt as necessary:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  x=5
  while ((x>1)); do
      echo mv somefolder/backup/data.$((x-1)) somefolder/backup/data.$x
      x=$((x-1))
  done
  cp somefolder/data somefolder/backup/data.1
  sleep 60
done
```

Comment: this overwrites the older files such that there are only 2 backups at any given point of time

Comment: I assumed you did not want infinite backups (?). I've modified the answer to include a loop where *x* control the number of backups.